# Flutter : How creat new list with changed index from exist list?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, random

if I have this List in Flutter :

```
var myList = ["a","b" , "c" , "d"];
```

How to create new list from myList by random index for each value like :

```
   ["b","c" , "a" , "d"];
```

or :

```
   ["a","c" , "d" , "b"];
```

or any other random list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var newList = [...myList];
newList.shuffle();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

myList = ["a","b" , "c" , "d"];
random.shuffle(myList)

print(mylist)
```

You follow this
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_shuffle.asp

Comment: this is for python ,I need in dart

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myList = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
myList.shuffle();
```